# Changing account password while a process is running under its identity

Tags: windows-xp, user-management

Does changing the account password on a Windows XP machine affect processes running under that account identity? Are there any issues I need to take into account when doing that? How about Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a Windows process gets its authentication token, it can use that token until the process exits. There are some differences though, such as accessing resources across the network, where an actual authentication takes place. Even then, if Kerberos was used and a kerb ticket generated, that kerb ticket will remain good until it expires (generally in less than 24 hours). XP and Win7 work the same way.

Answer (score 2):

No Problem for already running processes, except perhaps the running process "knows" the password and tries to use it (e.g. login to another computer in AD etc.)